# Decimales incorrectos en C

Tags: c, double, float

estoy realizando un proyecto en C, ha surgido un asunto que espero que la comunidad pueda ayudarme.

Estoy usando números decimales en concreto el tipo de dato es Float.
Al imprimir mi output veo que C esta haciendo una especie de redondeo. Por ejemplo:

**El numero que debería imprimir es .0751632 e imprime .0800000**

La forma en que imprimo es:

`printf("%f\n",aux_no->rutas[y]);`

La variable "aux_no" es una estructura con el array "rutas" como uno de sus miembros, ese array es del tipo float.

**¿No se si debería de cambiar de tipo de dato a Double?**

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para que deje de redondear de esa manera?**

Gracias a todos por leer.

Comment: Hola Victor, bienvenido a SOes, sería bueno que incluyas el código para ver la forma en la que estás imprimiendo el número.

Comment: la forma en que imprimo es printf("%f\n",aux_no->rutas[y]);  la variable "aux_no" es una estructura con el array "rutas" como uno de sus miembros, ese array es del tipo float. Saludos

Comment: Por favor puedes agregar más código, en particular donde declaras e inicializas `aux_no`

Comment: Lo que comentas es bastante extraño y no debería redondear nada, te aconsejo que uses el sufijo `f` cuando  inicialices un tipo `float`,  (`.0751632f` en vez de `.0751632`), de lo contrario interpreta (conversión implícita) el literal como `double`, aquí tienes la salida de tu ejemplo: https://ideone.com/YG5yjb , no se produce ningún tipo de redondeo (lo que da que pensar que en algún momento entre la inicialización y el `printf` ha habido una manipulación del valor).

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que debería imprimir `.0800000` si no lo puedes imprimir? ¿Cómo lo estás inicializando? Date cuenta que `printf` no imprime `float`s, solo `double`s. Todo `float` que pases como parámetro a `printf`, se transforma en `double` en el paso de parámetro. Aquí no debería haber problema de precisión. Además, la precisión por defecto de `%f` es de 6 decimales.

Copia y pega tu código en: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ y sustituye, en la linea de compilación, `-std=c++14` por `-x c -std=c++14`.

Comment: Y también prueba a forzar la precisión con `%.6f`, para 6 decimales, por ejemplo. Por último, sobre precisión, es importante tener en cuenta que `printf` va a redondear utilizando la misma política que utilice el procesador, que suele ser el **redondeo del banquero** (redondear al dígito par más cercano). Por ejemplo, redondear `2.34555` con 3 decimales da `2. 346`, mientras que `2.34655` da `2.346` también, porque en ambos casos, el número de 3 decimales par más cercano fué `2.346`.

Answer (score 2):

El array que defines dentro dentro de tu estructura debe ser tipo `double`  :

```
 double rutas[] = {91.023, 0.0751632, 2.03, 3.432, 7.023};
```

al imprimirlo puedes hacerlo como lo planteas en tu pregunta:

```
for(int y = 0; y<5; y++){
    printf("%f\n",rutas[y]);
}
```

con eso aseguras imprimir el valor deseado:

```
 0.0751632
```

Answer (score 1):

No parece haber manera de reproducir ese efecto

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){    

typedef struct aux_no_st{    
    float rutas[10];    
} aux_no_t;

aux_no_t aux_no_var;    
aux_no_var.rutas[1]= 0.0751632;    
aux_no_t *aux_no=&aux_no_var;   
int y=1;    
printf("%f",aux_no->rutas[1]);    
}
```

Obtengo este resultado

```
0.075163
```

¿Podrías probarlo y ver si sigue ocurriendo?

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento en C sobre el tipo float y double es el mismo, te va a realizar el mismo redondeo.

En la libreria *math.h* http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html puedes ver las diferentes funciones de redondeo disponibles. Algunos ejemplos:

```
#include <math.h>

float val =  0.751632;

float rounded_down = floorf(val * 1000) / 1000;   /* Result: 0.751 */
float nearest = roundf(val * 1000) / 1000;  /* Result: 0.752 */
float rounded_up = ceilf(val * 1000) / 1000;      /* Result: 0.752 */
```

Si esto no es suficiente, tendras que hacer tu propia funcion para tal efecto.

Answer (score 0):

El formato correcto para especificar la precisión usada por `printf()` es:

```
%f.(n-decimales)
```

En tu caso sería:

```
printf("%f.7\n",aux_no->rutas[y]);
```

Con esto se verían los 7 decimales del número que has colocado de ejemplo.

Pero aún sin especificar el valor 7, el valor por defecto es 6 decimales por lo que deberías obtener

```
0.075163
```

Por lo tanto el error con el redondeo o formato está mas atrás probablemente en la asignación al array.

Answer (score 0):

El redondeo es un tema que se dificulta para los que se inician en este mundo. Lo que sucede es que la precision del float es baja, lo que indica que al hacer varias operaciones, el error que se acumula, va creciendo y conduce a resultados que difieren grandemente del resultado real. En cambio, las variables **double** nos dan la posibilidad de sufragar un poco este problema, ya que la cantidad de bits que se encargan de manejar la parte de la precision del double es casi el doble de los del float, por tanto, es, por muuucho, más preciso. El especificador de conversion asociado al double es %lf.